# How to schedule a shopping cart promotion so that it starts and ends at a specific hour

Tags: promotions

How do you schedule a shopping cart promotion so that it starts and ends at a specific hour e.g. 9am rather than the default option of midnight?

Answer (score 3):

The catalog is updated and reindexed via Magento cronjob nightly.

To update all rules at a different time of day, you would need to override the cron schedule of `Mage_CatalogRule`, which is by default:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalogrule_apply_all>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate</model>
            </run>
        </catalogrule_apply_all>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

You can override it in a custom module `config.xml` like this, to update the catalog at 9am instead:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalogrule_apply_all>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 9 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
        </catalogrule_apply_all>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

---

To allow different rules to start/end at different times you would need to change a bit more:

- set the schedule to `0 * * * *` to update the catalog every hour
- change the `from_date` and `to_date` columns in the `catalogrule` table from `date` to `datetime`.
- adjust the forms in the admin panel to allow entering a time

**But I would not recommend this.** The update is an expensive operation, especially for large catalogs and you should avoid to run it more often than necessary.